# Select defined number of occurrences of a value in a table

Tags: mysql, mariadb

In my database I have the following table structure:

```
+-----+-------+-------+-------+---------------------+
| id  | pid   | dvc   | lst   | data                |
+-----+-------+-------+-------+---------------------+
| 150 | 22678 |  A    | 0x41  | data1               |
| 151 | 22678 |  A    | 0x41  | data2               |
| 152 | 22678 |  A    | 0x41  | data3               |
| 153 | 22678 |  A    | 0x42  | data1               |
| 154 | 22678 |  A    | 0x42  | data2               |
| 155 | 22678 |  A    | 0x42  | data3               |
| 156 | 22678 |  A    | 0x43  | data1               |
| 157 | 22678 |  A    | 0x43  | data2               |
| 158 | 22678 |  A    | 0x43  | data3               |
| 159 | 22678 |  B    | 0x41  | data1               |
| 160 | 22678 |  B    | 0x41  | data2               |
| 161 | 22678 |  B    | 0x41  | data3               |
| 162 | 22678 |  B    | 0x42  | data1               |
| 163 | 22678 |  B    | 0x42  | data2               |
| 164 | 22678 |  B    | 0x42  | data3               |
| 165 | 22678 |  B    | 0x43  | data1               |
| 166 | 22678 |  B    | 0x43  | data2               |
| 167 | 22678 |  B    | 0x43  | data3               |
| 168 | 22678 |  C    | 0x41  | data2               |
| 169 | 22678 |  C    | 0x41  | data3               |
| 170 | 22678 |  C    | 0x42  | data1               |
| 171 | 22678 |  C    | 0x42  | data2               |
| 172 | 22678 |  C    | 0x42  | data3               |
| 173 | 22678 |  C    | 0x43  | data1               |
| 174 | 22678 |  C    | 0x43  | data2               |
| 175 | 22678 |  C    | 0x43  | data3               |
| 176 | 22679 |  A    | 0x41  | data1               |
| 177 | 22679 |  A    | 0x41  | data2               |
| 178 | 22679 |  A    | 0x41  | data3               |
| 179 | 22679 |  A    | 0x42  | data1               |
| 180 | 22679 |  A    | 0x42  | data2               |
| 181 | 22679 |  A    | 0x42  | data3               |
| 182 | 22679 |  A    | 0x43  | data1               |
| 183 | 22679 |  A    | 0x43  | data2               |
| 184 | 22679 |  A    | 0x43  | data3               |
| 185 | 22679 |  B    | 0x41  | data1               |
| 186 | 22679 |  B    | 0x41  | data2               |
| 187 | 22679 |  B    | 0x41  | data3               |
| 188 | 22679 |  B    | 0x42  | data1               |
| 189 | 22679 |  B    | 0x42  | data2               |
| 190 | 22679 |  B    | 0x42  | data3               |
| 191 | 22679 |  B    | 0x43  | data1               |
| 192 | 22679 |  B    | 0x43  | data2               |
| 193 | 22679 |  B    | 0x43  | data3               |
| 194 | 22679 |  C    | 0x41  | data2               |
| 195 | 22679 |  C    | 0x41  | data3               |
| 196 | 22679 |  C    | 0x42  | data1               |
| 197 | 22679 |  C    | 0x42  | data2               |
| 198 | 22679 |  C    | 0x42  | data3               |
| 199 | 22679 |  C    | 0x43  | data1               |
| 200 | 22679 |  C    | 0x43  | data2               |
| 201 | 22679 |  C    | 0x43  | data3               |
+-----+-------+-------+-------+---------------------+
```

As you can see, each `pid` is repeated 3 times for each `lst`, with reapeating data.

Is it possible I can do a `SELECT` where only the three ocurrances of an `pid` is shown for each `dvc` ? So I can retrieve `data1` through `data3` for each `dvc` without repeating information, no matter from which `lst` it comes from.

So my table can look like this:

```
+-----+-------+-------+-------+---------------------+
| id  | pid   | dvc   | lst   | data                |
+-----+-------+-------+-------+---------------------+
| 150 | 22678 |  A    | 0x41  | data1               |
| 151 | 22678 |  A    | 0x41  | data2               |
| 152 | 22678 |  A    | 0x41  | data3               |
| 159 | 22678 |  B    | 0x41  | data1               |
| 160 | 22678 |  B    | 0x41  | data2               |
| 161 | 22678 |  B    | 0x41  | data3               |
| 168 | 22678 |  C    | 0x41  | data1               |
| 169 | 22678 |  C    | 0x41  | data2               |
| 170 | 22678 |  C    | 0x41  | data3               |
| 182 | 22679 |  A    | 0x43  | data1               |
| 183 | 22679 |  A    | 0x43  | data2               |
| 184 | 22679 |  A    | 0x43  | data3               |
| 185 | 22679 |  B    | 0x41  | data1               |
| 186 | 22679 |  B    | 0x41  | data2               |
| 187 | 22679 |  B    | 0x41  | data3               |
| 194 | 22679 |  C    | 0x42  | data1               |
| 195 | 22679 |  C    | 0x42  | data2               |
| 196 | 22679 |  C    | 0x42  | data3               |
+-----+-------+-------+-------+---------------------+
```

I tried `SELECT *, COUNT(*) c FROM mytable GROUP BY pid HAVING c < 3;` but got an empty as return.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```sql
SELECT MIN(id) AS id, pid, dvc, list, data
FROM tbl
GROUP BY pid, dvc, list, data
```